# ffmpeg : playing udp stream

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ffmpeg, streaming

I'm playing udp stream on iDevice using ffmpeg.
It does play the video and audio successfully.

The only issue I've got here that the following function call does take a long time

```
avformat_find_stream_info
```

It takes about 10 secs to complete the execution of this function.
The media that I'm playing has following properties :

```
MPEG-4 VIDEO v3 (DIV3)
RESOLUTION : 640x480
Frame rate : 25
```

Any ideas how to workaround this delay ?

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__decoding.html#gd42172e27cddafb81096939783b157bb) it is understandable why it is slow on the device. `avformat_find_stream_info` is designed to read a headerless stream to get the encoding info by trying multiple codecs. Does the stream not have headers?

Comment: I've streaming with VLC, so I guess its with header. Do you know what should be used for this, and how to handle this correctly ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with it but according to the documentation `avformat_open_input` will get the header information if available but it recommends to call `avformat_find_stream_info` in case there was no header information.

Answer (score 8):

I realize this is an old question, but I recently encountered this problem, so while this probably won't help the OP, I'll put down an answer for posterity's sake.

The short answer:

Set the `AVFormatContext` fields for `probesize` and/or `max_analyze_duration` to something smaller than the default, i.e.

```
std::string url_path = "...";
AVFormatContext *format_ctx = NULL;
avformat_open_input(&format_ctx, url_path.c_str(), NULL, NULL);
format_ctx->max_analyze_duration = 50000;
avformat_find_stream_info(format_ctx, NULL);
```

For the longer answer:

`avformat_find_stream_info` reads from the input data stream and tries to fill out the `AVFormatContext` based on the packets it sees. It can do this for up to the `max_analyze_duration` value as set in the `AVFormatContext` struct.

For say, local video files, it'll generally be very fast, but for network streams this can take a very long time (especially if the stream is damaged). This is where the long wait-times for `avformat_find_stream_info` come into play. The default value for `max_analyze_duration` is 5000000 (in units of AV_TIME_BASE), meaning that hypothetically, `avformat_find_stream_info` can be sampling packets from the input stream for up to that duration (IIRC AV_TIME_BASE is equivalent to microseconds, so the default maximum wait time is 5 seconds).

By setting the `max_analyze_duration` to something smaller, say 50,000 (~500ms) we force `avformat_find_stream_info` to choose what the `AVFormatContext` fields are with less information, while limiting the worst-case wait time to something more reasonable. In my experience this hasn't caused for any problems (although this may depend on how your video source is). The `probesize` field determines the number of bytes that `avformat_find_stream_info` can read from the stream. Note that if you set this value to be too low, you might be not able to get accurate codec information

Comment: 50,000 microsecond ~ 50 milliseconds

Comment: Just as an FYI, if you came across this because you were using ffmpeg or vlc command lines, you can use the "analyzeduration" option to override this, but you'll need to be on VLC 4 (presently that's the nightlies).